# How can I pass the variable to the to RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, exact-match

I want to pass the cookie as a variable .

```
letstr = cookie;
(/\bcookie\b/g).test('having cookie.');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Can you explain that further?

Comment: Typing "variable" and "regex" into the stackoverflow search finds your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pass the variable to the regEx

let x = "cookie";
let reg = new RegExp(`\\b${x}\\b`,'g');

x.test("having cookie");

\b will create /\b this. and let 'g' will be added to the end of the string